# Windows Azure Pack and Windows Azure integration

Tags: azure

if I install Windows Azure Pack for private cloud does that enable me to manage my VMs in Azure public cloud  with the same management portal on the WAPadmin ?

Answer (score 1):

You could manage your VMs in the Azure public space using Service Management Automation.  You would need to import the Azure module and then could automate all your management through there.

There are a couple of sample scripts on Script Center that would help you get started with this.  You can look at Connect to an Azure Subscription: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-to-an-Azure-f27a81bb
to see an example of how you connect to Azure.

There are also a couple of examples of managing Azure resources up on [Script Center](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=WindowsAzure&f%5B0%5D.Text=Windows%20Azure&f%5B1%5D.Type=SubCategory&f%5B1%5D.Value=WindowsAzure_automation&f%5B1%5D.Text=Automation).  These are all intended for Azure Automation, but should work in SMA in Windows Azure Pack as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Konube (www.konube.com)](http://www.konube.com). We solve this specific problem.

*Disclaimer: I work at Konube.*

Answer (score 0):

**The Short Answer is "No"**

Public Azure Resources can be managed only from the management portal either the new management portal https://portal.azure.com or https://manage.windowsazure.com.

**Private Azure Pack resources can be managed with the Azure Pack Management Portal. You need to install the portal separately, you can find the details of installing the Portal from this article.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/privatecloud/archive/2013/12/06/windows-azure-pack-installing-amp-configuring-series.aspx**

The article gives you very clear step by step process of install the on premise portal which can be access by people on your in your on-premise network.

I can see it would really cool to be able to manage both public and private cloud on the same portal :). **I would stand in queue for one of those myself. It will come soon now that we are blurring the line between on-premise and cloud everyday.**

Hope the response helps clarify your question,

**Happy to help, Yours Truly, -CB**